# Fetch models from JSON.file and store it localstorage Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

```
Collection.fetch().done(function(){
    console.log(Collection); // fetchs all the models and successfully print here 

    Collection.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage('Localstorage');
    console.log(localStorage); // Storage {length: 0}
});
```

The above code is to **fetch the data from .JSON file** and create models and even successfully prints it in console.log.

But i even have to store that in **LOCALSTORAGE**, as when i print localstorage in console it shows empty.

What i want is on page load get data from .json file using and **store these models in Localstorage , so that next time i will fetch data( i.e. models) from localstorage** not from file.

Comment: Are you talking about device local storage then try localStorage.a = "value" (as json string)

Comment: yup that will work, how do i do it while using fetch , so that whatever data i will get in fetch from JSON file will get stored in localstorage

Comment: if its Collection what you wanna save then do it as localStorage.coll = JSON.stringify(Collection); and can get as localStorage.coll whwn needed(just parse it)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the collection's `sync` function to place in the logic to first check cache then fetch from the remote location and update the cache so subsequent requests will pickup the cache.

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  sync: function(method, collection, options) {
    var cache, data, dfd = $.Deferred(),
        cacheId = "collectionCache";

    switch (method) {
      case "read":

        // Attempt to get the cache
        cache = sessionStorage.getItem(cacheId);

        // Check if the cache has anything
        if (cache) {
          console.log("Returning from cache");

          // If the cache exists, call the success callback and resolve the Deferred object
          options.success(cache);
          dfd.resolve(cache)
        } else {
          console.log("Returning from external data");

          // We would perform the ajax call here to fetch our JSON
          data = externalData

          // Set the data that came from the file into our session storage
          sessionStorage.setItem(cacheId, data);

          // Call the success callback and resolve the Deferred object with the data loaded from the file
          options.success(data);
          dfd.resolve(data);
        }
        break;
    }

    // By overriding the sync function for this collection, you would also have to define logic for the create, update and destory methods.

    return dfd.promise();
  }
});
```

Keep in mind, when you override the sync method of a model or collection, you also have to write the logic to handle the other methods that would be used such as `create`, `update`, and `destroy`.

More information about the `sync` method can be found in [Backbone's Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

I've also put together a fiddle to demonstrate this functionality.
http://jsbin.com/hazimi/1/edit?js,console